# What is actually $e$ ? Why $e$ is so significant over other real numbers ?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I had this question for a long time.

We always use it in differentiation,Integration , Logarithms ..etc.

What is its origin ?

What unique qualities does it have over other real numbers?

Comment: $e=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{LCM(1,2,3,\ldots,n)}$

Comment: It can be shown that $\frac{d}{dx}a^x = ka^x$. When $a=e$, $k=1$.